# Displaying ads on click events

Tags: wordpress, javascript-injection

This is my site https://daddyssolutions.com. I don't get any ad popups when directly enter my site to the address bar. But when searched my site on google and click the link in the results of my website I'm popups of unknown ads on click the site. But I didn't add any ads to the site. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure didn't install any ad code than it could be malware attack. There are couple of good online service which scan website to detect malware like `sucuri.net` or search google by **website malware scan online**